# Exim: Email to root ignores /etc/aliases and /root/.forward - always used qualifies domain name

Tags: ubuntu, email, exim

`dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` asks for a domain name to "qualify" email addresses of local users such as `root`. Let's say I've set this setting to `qualified.example.com` - this causes all email sent to simply `root` to go to `root@qualified.example.com`.

I instead want all email to `root` to be sent to `example@gmail.com`, but I want the qualified domain name setting left set to `qualified.example.com` for other reasons.

I've added this line to `/etc/aliases`

```
root: example@gmail.com
```

And I've also put `example@gmail.com` in `/root/.forward`

I've run `newaliases` and restarted `exim`, but no matter what I do, mail to `root` continues to always try to send to `root@qualified.example.com`, which doesn't even exist.

How can I force email to `root` to go to `example@gmail.com`?

This is on Ubuntu Server 14.04

My `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` looks like this:

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'               
dc_other_hostnames=''                             
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1'                   
dc_readhost=''                                    
dc_relay_domains=''                               
dc_minimaldns='false'                             
dc_relay_nets=''                                  
dc_smarthost=''                                   
CFILEMODE='644'                                   
dc_use_split_config='false'                       
dc_hide_mailname=''                               
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'                          
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

When I ran `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` I answered the qualified domain question like so:

```
The 'mail name' is the domain name used to 'qualify' mail addresses without a domain name.                  

This name will also be used by other programs. It should be the single, fully qualified domain name (FQDN). 

Thus, if a mail address on the local host is foo@example.org, the correct value for this option would be    
example.org.                                                                                                

This name won't appear on From: lines of outgoing messages if rewriting is enabled.                         

System mail name:                                                                                           

qualified.example.com_________
```

Although that setting doesn't appear in `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf`.  Should it?

I've noticed that the same issue happens on my Debian servers too.  I must be completely misunderstanding something about Exim and/or the `/etc/aliases` file, because they all seem to ignore my `/etc/aliases` root: example@gmail.com entry and they always send root's mail to root@qualified.example.com no matter what I try.  It also seems odd that a simple forwarding rule is so dependent on the mail servers main configuration?

Comment: Please could you include a copy of your `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` in your question, and also indicate if you have edited any other configuration file in the `/etc/exim4` directory. I suspect you've simply omitted to tell your local server that it itself is qualified.example.com, but when I see your `update-exim4.conf.conf` I'll be able to confirm that.

Comment: Hi @roaima ... I've added more details as requested.  Thanks.

Comment: those settings are stored in /etc/default/exim4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your host doesn't sufficiently know that it is supposed to be `qualified.example.com`. A local delivery to `root` is rewritten as `root@qualified.example.com`, which is (wrongly) considered to be elsewhere, so an off-host delivery is attempted.

You need to complete the process telling `exim4` that your local host really is `qualified.example.com`. Then, when it delivers to `root`, rewritten as `root@qualified.example.com` it will consider this as local delivery. It will then check the `/etc/aliases` file and perform off-host delivery to `example@gmail.com` per your instructions.

Let's assume your host's real DNS name is `myhost.contoso.com`. Rerun `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` and include these settings:

- System mail name: `myhost.contoso.com`
- Other destinations for which [local] mail is accepted: `myhost : qualified.example.com`
- Domains to relay mail for: *{empty}*
- Machines to relay mail for: *{empty}*

Then run `update-exim4.conf` and `invoke-rc.d exim4 restart`

Comment: Hey thanks for your help on this.  This did solve the issue on a Debian server, but in the end this problem on the Ubuntu server seemed to be caused by VestaCP, so I should have mentioned that I was running that.  For anyone else with the same problem running VestaCP, you need to add your version of "qualified.example.com" as a mail domain in the VestaCP control panel for some reason, otherwise root's forwarding won't work and gives the following error in the Exim mainlog: `remote host address is the local host`

Comment: Also good to know: Exim4 does **not** use `/etc/hosts` to determine which domain maps to localhost. It really only uses the domains entered by the question `Other destinations for which mail is accepted:`.

Answer (score 2):

Although that setting doesn't appear in `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf`. Should it?

That setting goes to /etc/mailname file. As long as the first (and only) line of /etc/mailname matches your /etc/hosts, it will be considered as a local delivery. E.g. you wanna use `qualified.example.com`, so you should have it in your /etc/mailname file and it should also be defined in /etc/hosts file, like: `127.0.0.1 qualified.example.com`. Be sure to define the same for ipv6 in your hosts file (or disable ipv6 for exim if you don't use it).